# Android Google Map crashes while launching

Tags: android, eclipse

With the following codes my google map crashes when the intent is going to be started. Please help me fix the code. Thanks in advance.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.googlemaps;

import info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCBZtSAObwgqcDwz7szpyXOxn3tCIhucdU" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**and the Logcat**

```
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): Process: info.androidhive.googlemapsv2, PID: 2117
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.googlemapsv2/com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.example.googlemaps.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     ... 11 more
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 7571000 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzaa(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzaz(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy.zzay(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zzvu(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zzb.zza(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.zza(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4785)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
08-11 07:42:23.320: E/AndroidRuntime(2117):     ... 21 more
```

That's it. And I use eclipse Juno and api is 4.4.2 API 19

Comment: When I google for "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file" I get about 52000 results. What did you do so far to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below MAP_KEY inside the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: It's already there,





<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCBZtSAObwgqcDwz7szpyXOxn3tCIhucdU" />

Comment: @Anupam, Please read my answer properly. I am telling you to add this new tag bellow your MAP_KEY tag. According to Map V2 version it is compulsory to add this tag for MAP.

Comment: You welcome. Since you are new to the Stackoverflow, Let me guide you. You should accept an answer by ticking the green tick mark besides the answer. This also helps future users.

Comment: Thanks Kedarnath. Thanks so much. It worked but still got some problem with the map. The map is not showing any real map at all but only google logo at the bottom.
Thanks again.
:

Comment: ok lets solve this too. MAP_KEY you are using is a debug key ?

Comment: What's a debug key? Today is my first day on google map integration on android so my question could sound very foolish.

Comment: How can I post logcat mssg here? I could not post that since the length of the mssg is too long for this post.

Comment: That's ok. Tell me how did you get this MAP_KEY ?

Comment: A snippet form logcat mssg
08-11 08:58:32.670: E/Google Maps Android API(2238): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.

But I created  the map registration just yesterday with my gmail account.

Comment: Did you complete the API_KEY process ?

Comment: I think did. but how can I make sure that I have completed that?

Comment: Did you use keystore while creating it ? Please visit this [help page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup).

Comment: No but what I did is,

Windows > Preferences > Android > Build and got the necessary fingerprint.

Comment: Have you enable V2 Service in console page ? I suggest you to read the content of that help page. I am leaving for the day now. see ya.